# document.this.style.display without jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

Can somebody help me with this?

I am trying to make this below script work and is supposed to hide the button after I click it. I have this being called through Ajax and PHP so I cannot use jQuery plus I am looping through a PHP script so I cannot put an ID to my button.

```
onmouseup="function(){document.this.style.display = none;}"

echo '<a href="" class="more4btn" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="origin" value="Comment" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" onmouseup="function(){document.this.style.display = none;}" onclick="MorePosts('.$user_id.','.$post_count.')">More</a>';
```

Comment: use this.style.display = none;

Comment: remove `document.this.` and have `this.`

Comment: Change `function(){document.this.style.display = none;}` to `function(){this.style.display = none;}`. Document not needed there.

Comment: echo '<a href="" class="more4btn" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="origin" value="Comment" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" onmouseup="function(){document.this.style.display = none;}" onclick="MorePosts('.$uid.','.$pcount.')">More</a>';

Comment: What's "`document.this`?" don't you mean `this`? `document` doesn't have a `this` property... Also, eval string listeners ahhhhhhh

Comment: I try'd that no luck..

Comment: ...also, why do you have a function declaration that does nothing? You really need to find a good book or tutorial about JS...

Comment: I dunno. lol I am trying to change the css of this button which is created in ajax and it is also created in a php loop so every time I click the button it will load more content but then I want the  button I just clicked to disappear because there is a new button generated And your help is very appreciated :)

Comment: I didn't have the function dec til I try'd someone Else's code I've never done it like that before!

Comment: @Tushar Gupta - Sorry about the edit over yours, we must've have done it at the very same time.

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
onmouseup="this.style.display = 'none';"
```

Comment: still didn't work but it could be because I had to change the ' to " on 'this' "its echoed out in PHP" onmouseup="this.style.display = "none";"

Comment: I meant on the 'none' part sry